# I need to repoint a Domain on a Names host to another server that runs my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, dns, cname, a-records

I have a Domain host (JustHosts.com) that host my domain name:

```
mydomain.com
```

I have another server with a WordPress site on it which is accessed directly as:

```
mywordpress.com/wpsite1
```

I want this to be accessed via mydomain.com, so:

```
mydomain.com -> mywordpress.com/wpsite1
```

The URL should stay as mydomain.com, not go back to mywordpress.com/wpsite1.

I can add the following types of records:

```
A
CNAME
MX
TXT
SRV
AAAA
```

What should I do on my domain host to make this change?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this in particular condition where we **use subdomain to pointin**g to the WordPress site and the **Wordpress site itself is installed on a host provider that is using [cPanel](http://cpanel.net/)**.

Formerly I simply set CName on subdomain **blog.mydomain.com** to the subdomain where my Wordpress site is installed. Unfortunately this pointing was resulting a redirection like this:

```
http://blog.mydomain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi
```

Searching for a solutiom then I found this documentation:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/installation/

It is actually a documentation for a plugin to map any blog/site on a WordPressMU or WordPress 3.X network to an external domain. I didn't install the plugins I just marked that for cPanell users we need to put the mydomain.com as a parked domain in cPanel where the Wordpress site is installed.

So with the cPanel I uninstalled my WordPress and rearrange the installation step as below:

```
1. Put mydomain.com as a parked domain   
2. Re install WordPress using blog.mydomain.com
```

Viola! The blog.mydomain.com is running the WordPress perfectly and stay in blog.mydomain.com without any error or redirection to other domain.